# How to navigate nested JSON with Event API for ruby filter

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have a json file , for which i am not able to navigate to the events with logstash 5.0.

I want to extract the name of cars from below
using get and set method of ruby as per the documentation
event.get('[message][cars][name]')

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
 }
```

Here is my conf file

```
input {  
      file {

          sincedb_path =>  "..../bin/sincedb_path.txt"
          path => "..../test1.json"
          type => "test"
          start_position => "beginning"

      }
}



filter {

ruby {
    code => "
test = event.get('[message][cars][name]')
event.set('result',test)
    "
    }

}

output {  
stdout { codec => rubydebug}

 }
```

With the above config file i get nil value.
Please let me know correct way to navigate to the path

Comment: Since your `cars` property is an array, you also need to specify which index to take: `[message][cars][0][name]`

Comment: I have tried this as well, its giving me nil value only. I think i am not sure of the right path for this get event. Please suggest